# Python file transfer only works in localhost and fails between two machines

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, file-transfer

I have written following python code for file transfer. It works fine in localhost environment. It fails between two different physical machines. I get the file but with incomplete data. There is also invalid literal error while converting string to long while sending file size to client. I can't figure out why?

**server.py**

```
from socket import *
import thread
import os

l = {}
def handler(clientsocket, clientaddr):
    print "Accepted connection from: ", clientaddr 
    while 1:
        data = clientsocket.recv(8192)
        if not data:
            break
        else:           
            print "The following data was received - ",data
            l[clientaddr] = data
            print l
            print "Opening file - ",data
            fp = open(data,'r')
            size = os.path.getsize(data)
            clientsocket.send(str(size))
            strng = "hi"
            print size
            while size > 0:
                strng = fp.read(8192)
                clientsocket.send (strng)
                size = size - 8192

    clientsocket.close()



if __name__ == "__main__":

    host = 'localhost'
    port = 55573
    buf = 8192

    addr = (host, port)

    serversocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

    serversocket.bind(addr)

    serversocket.listen(5)

    while 1:
        print "Server is listening for connections\n"

        clientsocket, clientaddr = serversocket.accept()
        thread.start_new_thread(handler, (clientsocket, clientaddr))
    serversocket.close()
```

**client.py**

```
from socket import *
import os
if __name__ == '__main__':

    host = '10.1.99.176'
    port = 55573
    buf = 8192

    addr = (host, port)

    clientsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

    clientsocket.connect(addr)

    while 1:
        fname = raw_input("Enter the file name that u want>> ")
        if not fname:
            break
        else:
            clientsocket.send(fname)
            print "\nThe file will be saved and opened- "
            fname = '/home/coep/Downloads/'+fname
            nf = open(fname,"a")
            strng = "hi"
            size = clientsocket.recv(16)
            size = long(size)
            print size  
            while size > 0:
                strng = clientsocket.recv(8192)
                        if not strng:
                            break
                        nf.write(strng)
                size = size - 8192
                if size > 500000:
                    print size

            nf.close()
            fname = 'viewnior '+ fname
            print fname
            os.system(fname)
```

Comment: different machine on same ip domains?

Comment: Maybe you have a firewall in place that's blocking port 55573 ?

Comment: yes. They are in LAN.

Answer (score 1):

In server.py, you are using

host = 'localhost' and it will just bind the port to localhost Ip address i.e. 127.0.0.1.

Change it to host='0.0.0.0' and it will bind the specific port to all available interfaces.

Update: Another reason can be that buffer size is just too big and with 8192, it may get blocked forever because last transfer was never able to fill the buffer. To get around it, set the timeout to makesure to proceed if the buffer doesn't fill up. In client.py, try changing,

```
    clientsocket.timeout(5)
    while size > 0:
            try:
                strng = clientsocket.recv(8192)
                if not strng:
                    break
                nf.write(strng)
                size = size - 8192
                if size > 500000:
                    print size
             except:
                 nf.write(string)
```

Also 8192 is quite big size and try to reduce the size to 1000-1300 bytes. Chossing 8192 is not giving you any advantage as the packets will still move in the fragments with upper limit of MTU which is generally 1436 bytes.

Comment: Its already done. But still there is incomplete data transfer.

Comment: Now, I have turned buffer size to 512 bytes and program works fine but still there is loss of many bytes.

Comment: Does the loss bytes always appear at end of file ? If yes than i would doubt your calculation for size somehow. Instead of doing "size = size - 8192", you can do "size - len(strng)" but can't says if thats causing issue in your test env.